# Seaborn tsplot displays counterintuitive CI bands

Tags: pandas, time-series, seaborn, standard-deviation

I'm using Seaborn's `tsplot` to visualize a time series (data available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2u3MNOqrn8caHpmYzRVTUZKYlk)) :

```
        Vent (m/s)  year month  date               mois

7.9456207374248     1998    1   2012-01-01 00:00:59 1

7.49342837173539    1998    1   2012-01-01 01:00:59 1

7.49853611345398    1998    1   2012-01-01 02:00:59 1

7.61488603321423    1998    1   2012-01-01 03:00:59 1

7.70778826901725    1998    1   2012-01-01 04:00:59 1

7.78203058333749    1998    1   2012-01-01 05:00:59 1

8.00562302385017    1998    1   2012-01-01 06:00:59 1

8.14370922860093    1998    1   2012-01-01 07:00:59 1

8.28552955459094    1998    1   2012-01-01 08:00:59 1

8.60182223260882    1998    1   2012-01-01 09:00:59 1

9.14166286842826    1998    1   2012-01-01 10:00:59 1




sns.tsplot(value = 'Vent (m/s)', data = df, time ='mois', condition="year", unit = "date", 
       interpolate=False,
       estimator = np.nanmean,
       #ci=[68, 100],
      )
```

Here's the output :

[image]

I find the CI bands quite counterintuitive : I'm expecting the CI to display the standard error for each month, but the CI value is different. Indeed, `df[df["month"] == 1]["Vent (m/s)"].std()` returns `3.5529405282100215` while the plot reads less than 1.

Did I do or understand something wrong?

Comment: can you include a subset of your data?

Comment: @Grr done. I did not manage to display it in a beautiful way, but here it is!

Comment: What made you expect the standard error to be displayed? There's no mention of standard error in the docstring for the function.

Comment: I also think you missed this line from the docs "This function is intended to be used with data where observations are nested within sampling units that were measured at multiple timepoints."

Comment: The default is to show the bootstrap 68% CI which is equivalent to the standard error of the mean. But the standard error of the mean is *not* equivalent to the standard deviation of the observations...